# Are filter and sort commutative operations in database/linq query?

Tags: linq, sorting, filter

For an arbitrary collection of objects, would following two LINQ expressions always give the same result (given that LINQ provider is the same):

1. `var result = list.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).Where(x => x.Age > 18);`
2. `var result = list.Where(x => x.Age > 18).OrderBy(x => x.FirstName);`

Comment: How could they not return the same result? It would be a serious bug, as they logically should.

Comment: Two different objects that have equal values for "FirstName" may be returned in different orders from one query to the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [`Enumerable<T>.OrderBy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) is specified to be a [stable sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), [`Queryable<T>.OrderBy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549264.aspx) is not.

In other words, no, since the sort is not guaranteed to be stable, the two queries are not guaranteed to give the same result for all providers. At the very least, the results may be ordered in a different order.

Comment: Does this applies if IQueryable<T> provider is the same for both cases (eg. Entity Framework) in original question?

Comment: @matori82 Entity framework has one further complication, that the order in the underlying SQL is not stable to begin with. If you run the first query, insert a new row into the table and run the exact same query again, you may not get the same ordering re. values that sort equal, _even if the new row is not included in the result_. Values that sort as equal may come out in another order. Currently, EF builds the _same sql_ from both your queries though, but that is an EF specific implementation detail :)